# Doctrine - A new entity was found through the relationship Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I had table Type and Table lignePanier .
The column type_id in lignePanier table is a foreign key which refers the id in lignePanier table.

I have set the relationship is that a type may have many lignesPanier. I have created the entities of both table.

Also , I had Table panier which may have many lignesPanier.

My pobject is to add a, existing type to an existing lignePanier
And save all in database

here is my type entity :

```
 /**
 * One type has Many lignesPanier.
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EK\EcommerceBundle\Entity\lignePanier", mappedBy="type" , cascade={"persist"} )
 */

private $lignesPanier;
```

here is my lignePanier entity : `

```
/**
 * Many lignes panier have One type.
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="EK\PlateformeBundle\Entity\Type", 
 inversedBy="lignesPanier" )
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */

private $type;`
```

Here is Panier entity :

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="montant", type="float", nullable=true)
 */
private $montant;


/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="num_article", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $numArticles;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="numero", type="string", length=255 , nullable=true)
 */
 private $numero;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EK\EcommerceBundle\Entity\lignePanier", mappedBy="panier" , cascade={"persist"})
*/
private $lignesPanier;
```

here where I want to save all in database :

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$panier = $user->getPanier();

if ($this->get('session')->get('vehicule') != null )
{
    $type = $this->get('session')->get('vehicule');
    $lignePanier->setType($type);
}

$lignePanier->setPanier($panier);
$lignePanier->setPiece($piece);
$lignePanier->setPrix($prix);

$panier->addLignePanier($lignePanier);
$panier->setNumArticles($panier->getNumArticles() + $form->getData()->getQuantite() );


$montant = $panier->getMontant() + $prix ; 
$panier->setMontant($montant);


$em->flush();
```

My code did'nt work and I got this error :

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 
'EK\EcommerceBundle\Entity\lignePanier#type' that was not configured to 
cascade persist operations for entity: Essence 1.6 i 90 cv Boite 
automatique. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call 
EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist 
this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade=
{"persist"}).
```

Comment: cascade={"persist"} is on the wrong side, try to put it in the LignePanier entity.

Comment: I tried it but I got this error : Notice: Undefined index: 0000000068fb94b5000000007a524eeb

Comment: Is Panier an entity ? can you show them to us ?

Comment: yes It is an entity

Answer (score -2):

I tried this code and it works but Idid'nt understand why :

```
                $user = $this->getUser();
                $panier = $user->getPanier();

                if ($this->get('session')->get('vehicule') != null )
                {
                       $type = $this->get('session')->get('vehicule');
                       $Type = $em-
                       >getRepository('EKPlateformeBundle:Type')-
                       >find($type->getId());
                       $lignePanier->setType($Type); 
                }

                $lignePanier->setPanier($panier);
                $lignePanier->setPiece($piece);
                $lignePanier->setPrix($prix);

                $panier->addLignePanier($lignePanier);
                $panier->setNumArticles($panier->getNumArticles() +  
                $form->getData()->getQuantite() );

                $montant = $panier->getMontant() + $prix ; 
                $panier->setMontant($montant);


                $em->flush();
```

`